# Is it possible to hide the navigationcontroller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a iphone apps with a navigation controller, dans I want to push a view but in this view the navigationController must be hidden, or if it's not possible, is it possible to only hide de left button, so the user can't go back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking for this?

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = TRUE;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the back button by adding:

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

To your viewWillAppear method in the controller.

You can also:

```
self.navigationController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;     // Hide the tabBar if there is one
self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = YES;        // Hide the top bar on the navigation Controller
```

Answer (score 0):

self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```